# Is there a way to dynamically add streams?

Tags: orleans

I'm trying to design a system where streams (backed by an external service, ex. an azure queue storage) may be added or removed dynamically.  When a new stream appears, a set of cooperating agents are created to handle this new data stream.

All samples seems to statically configure the available streams (at startup). Is there a way to add and remove streams dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can subscribe and push to any stream without the need to create it explicitly upfront, much in the same way as with virtual actors - the stream will be created (activated) on the first use

Comment: I understand that, but how to handle cases where streams providers are dynamically added? For instances, if persistent queues are dynamically created and the system must consume data comming from those queues.